# xcode How to link UIAlertview action to another viewcontroller?

Tags: xcode, uialertview, viewcontroller

Im am trying to link one of my buttons from the UIAlertView that pops up so that It changes to another viewcontroller. Basically, the cancel already works, but when Next is clicked it doesnt, and i don't know how to link to another viewcontroller. Please help.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController() <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Test" message: @"Message" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Redeem", nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 1){ //Next
        UIViewController* newView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working...Just create object of viewcontroller that you want to present instead of

```
UIViewController* newView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

like

```
SecondViewController * newView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

if you are using xib.

Or

```
SecondViewController * newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
```

if you are using storyboard(if you want to go through coding).

and then write

```
[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

line.

Comment: Here is the project file, please tell me what i am meant to change.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5ye9jvxonyxxgd/StackOverflow%20Example.zip?dl=0

Comment: I dont have that much of time...plus you have to learn on your own...just watch any demo "how to present view controller in ios".